# Where do I put VBA code?

Tags: database, vba, function, ms-access

Gustav very provided me with code but I have no idea where to put it.

Am I correct in putting the function into a module? What about the other two lines of code?

I'm used to query expressions, but afaik I can't put VBA code in there.

I've tried all sorts of things, but I keep getting "#Name?" on my form.

Gustav's post:

> I guess you could calculate like this:
>
> ```
> RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday    (HireDate), HireDate))
> ```
>
> From then on, you can count full months:
>
> ```
> RetentionMonths = Months(RetentionStartDate, Date)
> ```
>
> using a function like this:
>
> ```
> Public Function Months( _
>   ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
>   ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
>   Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
>   As Integer
>
> ' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
> '
> ' Calculates correctly for:
> '   negative differences
> '   leap years
> '   dates of 29. February
> '   date/time values with embedded time values
> '   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
> '
> ' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
> ' linear sequence of month counts.
> ' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
> ' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
> ' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
> ' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
> '   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
> ' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
> '   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
> '
> ' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
> ' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
> ' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
> ' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
> ' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
> ' This behaviour mimics that of Int().
>
> ' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
> ' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
> ' when the resulting year is a common year.
> '
> ' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
>
>   Dim intDiff   As Integer
>   Dim intSign   As Integer
>   Dim intMonths As Integer
>
>   ' Find difference in calendar months.
>   intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
>   ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
>   ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
>   ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
>   If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
>     intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
>     intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
>   Else
>     intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
>     If intSign <> 0 Then
>       ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
>       intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
>     End If
>     intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
>   End If
>
>   ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
>   Months = intMonths - intDiff
>
> End Function
> ```

Comment: Yes, put it into a general module and then it can be called from anywhere, even in a query. In a textbox on form the expression would be like: `=Months([RetentionStartDate], Date())` where RetentionStartDate would be replaced with appropriate field name.

Comment: Correction, replace RetentionStartDate with the DateAdd() expression.

Comment: To clarify, is this what you mean?

=Months([DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday (HireDate), HireDate))],Date())

Comment: Sorry I was not clear on use of  [ ]. They go around field names, not an entire expression. So like [HireDate].

Comment: Like this? =Months(DateAdd("ww",14,DateAdd("d",[vbSaturday]-Weekday([HireDate]),[HireDate])),Date())

Comment: No, vbSaturday is a VBA constant not a field. And unfortunately will not work in Access textbox or query. I should have noticed that. Must use the number equivalent which is 7.

Comment: June, thank you so very much. That explains a lot. I'm slowly learning! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use in a query, create a helper function:

```
Public Function RetentionMonths(ByVal HireDate As Date) As Integer

    Dim RetentionStartdate As Date

    RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(HireDate), HireDate))

    RetentionMonths = Months(RetentionStartDate, Date)

End Function
```

Like the `Months` function, save this function in your code module, and your query could look like:

```
Select *, RetentionMonths([HireDate]) As RetentionMonths
From YourTable
```